# The other side of Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

"Assume F is a consistent formalized system which contains elementary arithmetic. Then F does not prove F is consistent."

So, if Peano arithmetic is consistent, it can't prove "Peano arithmetic is consistent". But what if Peano arithmetic can prove "Peano arithmetic is inconsistent"? Would it still possibly be consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is consistent with PA that PA is inconsistent.

How does this work? By Goedel's completeness theorem, *consistency* is the same as *satisfiability*: a consistent theory has a model. So if PA+"PA is inconsistent" is consistent, it better have a model. How can that be?

Well, a model of $PA$ is a collection of things called "numbers", together with a notion of addition and of multiplication, which satisfy some properties. The usual natural numbers is merely one such model. In general, a *nonstandard model* of $PA$ will have "infinite" elements: that is, besides the usual natural numbers, such a model will have lots of $c$s such that $c>0, c>1, c>2, . . . $

Now, if a model thinks that PA is inconsistent, that means the model thinks "There is a proof of 0=1 in PA" - or, more specifically, there is a number *coding* such a proof. So the model will have an element $c$ which it thinks codes a proof of inconsistency. But, if such a $c$ is *infinite*, then it doesn't really code a proof! It codes a "nonstandard proof", something the model thinks is a proof.

---

In a comment, you ask how Goedel's theorem is really an "incompleteness theorem" if it leaves the possibility of PA proving its own inconsistency. Let's address that:

- First of all, we usually assume that PA is *true*. A fortiriori, this means PA is *consistent* - and since it's true, that means it doesn't prove that it's *in*consistent.
- That's a rather strong assumption. Can we do better? Well, Goedel observed that we don't really need PA to be true, merely that it is [correct about sentence of the form "$\exists x[P(x)]$"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) (and in fact even less is necessary - we can restrict attention to such sentences where $P$ uses only bounded quantifiers).
- This was how Goedel left it, and he and others asked if the situation could be improved:

> Can we prove "If $PA$ is consistent, then $PA$ is incomplete"?

[This was answered affirmatively by Rosser.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser's_trick)

Here's what he did: whereas Goedel looked at the sentence $$G_{PA}:\quad\mbox{"There is no PA-proof of me,"}$$ Rosser looked at the sentence $$R_{PA}:\quad\mbox{"For any PA-proof of me, there is a shorter PA-disproof of me"}.$$ Via Goedel's original argument, $PA$ doesn't prove $R_{PA}$ if $PA$ is consistent; the new part is the other direction.

Suppose $PA$ proves $\neg R_{PA}$, via a proof $\pi$. Then $PA$ proves "There is a proof of $R_{PA}$ with no proof of $\neg R_{PA}$ shorter than it" (since this is exactly what $\neg R_{PA}$ says). Well, there are only finitely many proofs shorter than $\pi$ - so we can check them one by one in $PA$. Since $PA$ is consistent, this means there is in fact no proof of $R_{PA}$ at all; so in particular, there is no proof of $R_{PA}$ shorter than $\pi$. But that means that our check of proofs-shorter-than-$\pi$ shows that, in fact, $R_{PA}$ is *true*! Since it verifies that any proof of $R_{PA}$ would have to be longer than $\pi$.

Goedel's original argument *was* an incompleteness result: it showed that *under reasonable assumptions* $PA$ is incomplete. It's just that those assumptions were stronger than mere consistency. Rosser got the assumptions down to the absolute minimum (any inconsistent theory proves everything), but that shouldn't be seen as devaluing Goedel's argument.

Comment: In that case, why is it still called an "incompleteness" theorem? An incompleteness theorem is supposed to be a theorem saying that for a certain sentence s, PA cannot prove s, and PA cannot prove [not s]. All the proofs of this second incompleteness theorem I've read only prove that, if PA is consistent, then PA cannot prove "PA is consistent". None prove that if PA is consistent, then PA cannot prove "PA is not consistent".

Comment: @KopaLeo See my edit.

Comment: @KopaLeo I've added the details of Rosser's argument.

Comment: Yes, I learned of Rosser's argument just today and it made me realize that the usual proof of the second incompleteness theorem is assuming more than just consistency. May I ask what's the minimal assumption we need to prove that PA cannot prove "PA is not consistent"? Is this an open question of sorts?

Comment: @KopaLeo Well, the obvious assumption is $1$-consistency: if $S$ is a formula with only bounded quantifiers, and $PA$ proves $\exists xS(x)$, then there really is some $x$ satisfying $S(x)$. But this is too strong: maybe $PA$ doesn't prove that it's inconsistent, but $PA$ *does* prove that $ZFC$ is inconsistent! This is a possibility since $ZFC$ is much stronger than $PA$. In fact, it can't be easily ruled out that $PA+Con(PA)$ is consistent, but $PA+Con(PA)+Con(PA+Con(PA))$ isn't! So the "optimal" assumption - if it exists - is much weaker than 1-consistency. (cont'd)

Comment: Well, obviously the optimal assumption exists - it's exactly "$PA$ doesn't prove it's own inconsistency"! :P Presumably you're looking for some assumption which at first glance is weaker than this. The dearth of a fine hierarchy of weak consistency principles, though, makes the existence of such a thing unlikely. The worst bit is that until we formalize what we mean by such a thing, we can't hope to prove that one exists! In this state of ill-posedness, I wouldn't call it an open question; and I don't think precisiating (blame Zadeh :P) it is actively pursued. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Is PA+Con(PA)+Con(PA+Con(PA)) consistent?

Comment: @KopaLeo Assuming PA is true? Certainly! For example, ZFC proves that that theory and much, much more is consistent.

Comment: @KopaLeo And (again, under *reasonable hypotheses*) we can iterating this - indeed, we can go [infinite](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12865/using-consistency-to-create-new-axioms-in-set-theory)! This was originally suggested by Turing in his Ph.D. thesis and paper of the same title ["Ordinal Logics"](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-45/1/161.full.pdf) and later studied by a number of people; see chapters 13-15 of the book [Inexhaustibility](https://www.amazon.com/Inexhaustibility-Non-Exhaustive-Treatment-Lecture-Notes/dp/1568811756) for a more up-to-date treatment of the subject.